# How to generate OData v4 Client for Silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight, asp.net-web-api, odata, generator, odata-v4

We're trying to get set up with Web API 2.2 and OData v4 for ASP.NET + Silverlight 5.

Initiall POC had a Unit Test project connecting using Simple.OData. This worked great. But we've been unable to set up an OData Client on Silverlight 5.

Using Client Code Generator v4 and keep getting error

> The type or namespace name 'Client' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.OData' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Workspaces\GKS\Main\Source\Simutek.Gks\Source\Simutek.Gks.UI.SL.Common\GksODataClient.cs Simutek.Gks.UI.SL.Common

Packages:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Client" version="6.12.0" targetFramework="sl50" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="6.12.0" targetFramework="sl50" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="6.12.0" targetFramework="sl50" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Spatial" version="6.12.0" targetFramework="sl50" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="sl50" />
```

References look good and we've also tried AssemblyBinding in app.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.OData.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.12.0.0" newVersion="6.12.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.OData.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.12.0.0" newVersion="6.12.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.12.0.0" newVersion="6.12.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

**Update:** Indeed, while the **Microsoft.OData.Client** NuGet package installs on Silverlight it does in fact not specify SL5 in its targets.
I now see that the package only targets

> portable-net45+wp8+win8+wpa

So while I can get things going in a PCL project, I can't do so in one targeting Silverlight 5.

Is there a work around, anyone who have achieved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight does not support the code generated by Microsoft's OData v4 Client Code Generator visx (OData Client T4), but no one's forcing you to use generated code.

Simply use the lib of your choice to create a connection to the OData service and reuse your own types (business objects).

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the PCLs that support Silverlight, two candidates are ODataLib (Microsoft.OData.Core) and Simple.OData.Client, the latter is built on the top of ODataLib. None of them supports class generation but it shouldn't be a big deal to roll your own.

Comment: I'm using your great lib Simple.OData, but the generated classes (which I don't want to use anyway) reference Microsoft.OData.Client which won't fly if the PCL targets SL5. Skipping generated classes as you suggest sounds great, but I haven't found any examples on this. You got an idea of where to look?

Comment: Ok, think I almost got it now. Simply removed the generated class, T4 template and all, since I don't use them.
I init a ODataClient and use For<[MyOwnEntity]> since this worked in previous tests. It builds, but trying to run generates a MethodAccessException by Simple.OData.Client.FluentCommand..DisplayClass..to access method AnonymousType..get_[MyProperty].
Curious, since I don't have any private setters. Why would they be when generated with reflection?

Comment: Try using POCO - plain C# classes not referencing anything from Microsoft.OData.Client. Look at service metadata and map the columns to the C# types. I am working on extending Simple.OData.Client with type generator but it may take a month or two until it's ready. But defining types manually is straightforward.

Comment: Look at this example of entities for Microsoft's TripPin OData sample:

https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/blob/master/Simple.OData.Client.IntegrationTests/TripPinEntities.cs

Comment: I am using a simple PCL targetted at .Net 4.5 and SL5.
By the error it sounds like reflection issues from using Type.GetFields instead of Type.GetProperties in a PCL?
http://i.imgur.com/bODjDlH.png

Comment: Not sure I understood the question. Perhaps you should formulate it as another SO question.